# Is a non-associative MPI_Op possible?

Tags: mpi

It's possible to [create an `MPI_Op`](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Op_create.html) that can be marked non-commutative.

Is it possible to make/use an `MPI_Op` that is not associative? If not, why not?

Let's use `MPI_Reduce` as a hypothetical use.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a cluster of 3 nodes, each with 2 cores, and each core owns 1 value (v1, v2, ..., v6). Suppose you have a clever MPI implementation that is aware of this topology, and performs the reduction so as to minimize inter-node communications. It does this by computing the subtotal on each node, then passing the subtotals from one node to the other. In other words:

1. Node 1 computes v1 + v2.
2. In parallel with step 1., Node 2 computes v3 + v4 and Node 3 computes v5 + v6.
3. Node 1 sends (v1 + v2) to Node 2, who adds it to its own subtotal. The result is (v1 + v2) + (v3 + v4).
4. Node 2 passes this result to Node 3, who adds it to its own subtotal. The end result is:

**( (v1 + v2) + (v3 + v4) ) + (v5 + v6)**

Now, imagine that you want to perform the same operation on the same data, but this time you have 2 nodes with 3 cores each. Because the implementation wants to minimize inter-node message passing, the end result will now be:

**(v1 + v2 + v3) + (v4 + v5 + v6)**

If the + operation is not associative, then these two results could be completely different. Obviously, this is not something you'd want.

---

The bottom line is that non-associative operations are not fit for parallel evaluation. Non-associativity means that the order in which you "add" values together matters, which effectively means that the operations need to be executed serially if you want consistent, well-defined results.

Comment: The same optimization argument can be made for commutativity. Why is that one optional, then?

Comment: @Adam, non-commutative operators can still be evaluated in parallel. Commutativity allows arbitrary evaluation trees to be used instead of strictly in-order trees. The latter might not map well to the underlying network topology with certain arrangement of ranks and result in slow evaluation.

Comment: @Adam Non-commutativity is not as great a hindrance. Consider 4 nodes with 2 cores each. If the operation is associative but not commutative, then Node 4 can still calculate a subtotal with Node 3, and then wait for the combined subtotal from Nodes 1 and 2. Take a look at some parallel algorithms (e.g. [parallel prefix sum](https://www.google.com/search?q=parallel+prefix+sum+algorithm)), and you should be able to see the difference yourself.

Comment: I understand why associativity is helpful. But there are also cases where a non-associative operation needs to be done, regardless of performance cost. What I'm hearing from you guys is that MPI only helps you do parallel work and you should build your own potentially serial semantics yourself. Is that right?

Comment: @Adam I think the crux of the matter is that MPI provides functions that would be cumbersome for users to implement themselves (correctly and efficiently). Sure, there could be a Reduce function with an order argument for non-associative operations, but you can achieve the same result with one Send and one Recv, and it would be as efficient as any MPI implementation could get.